# Renaming a column in prisma giving me an error The database schema is not empty

Tags: next.js, prisma

I followed the below article when renaming the column.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/migrate/developing-with-prisma-migrate/customizing-migrations#example-rename-a-field

When I run the below command after renaming the column in schema.prisma file I get the error **The database schema is not empty. Read more about how to baseline an existing production database: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-baseline**

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name rename-migration --create-only
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only way I could get it to work by deleting the migrations folder and running npx prisma migrate dev again. Is there anyway that I can get it to work without deleting the migrations folder?